# How Do I Code a Spring JDBC DAO That Supports a Variable Number of Result Sets

Tags: spring, jdbc

I need help writing a Spring JDBC DAO that is passed the name of a stored procedure and executes it.

I know how to execute a stored procedure using Spring JDBC.  I even know how to input the name of the stored procedure to execute.

The challenge I'm having is that the number of result sets returned is variable.  One stored procedure may return a single result set, another may return twelve, another three, etc.  One good thing is that each of the result sets will use the same Row Mapper.

The specific problem I'm having is getting each of the result sets to call the Row Mapper.  Since I don't know the number of result sets that will be returned I don't believe I can code any .returningResultSet's in my code.  So how do I get each of the variable number of result sets to call the Row Mapper?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Tim

Comment: So basically you have N stored procedures and each of them returns 1-K ResultSets and each of the ResultSets has exactly the same fields?

Comment: R4J, yes to the N stored procedures and yes to the 1-K result sets.  The result sets won't have exactly the same fields, but I need to map everything to Strings so if I'm given a ResultSet object I can iterate through the fields in the Result Set and get their values.  That's why I'm thinking I can use the same RowMapper.